# Cleanly stop a running JRuby scriptlet

Tags: java, ruby, multithreading, jruby

I am running a Ruby script from Java using JRuby like so:

```
public class ScriptletRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ScriptingContainer scriptingContainer = new ScriptingContainer();
        scriptingContainer.runScriptlet(/*My script*/); // this is a blocking call, never returns
    }
}
```

I pass this runnable to a new thread and start the thread. When I want to stop the script from running, I can't seem to find any way to tell the `ScriptingContainer` to stop executing the script. Even if I make it a member and call `terminate()` on it, the script just doesn't stop. If you run the script from the command line you can cleanly shut it down with `Ctrl+C`. There must be a way to achieve this with JRuby.

Comment: I believe the standard is to wrap the scripting container in a try block and have a finally that calls `terminate()` on it. Are you sure terminate isn't working, because I think that sends a sigint to the process which is what pressing Ctrl+c does.

Comment: There also appears to be a case with `JSR223` where you need to do some other stuff, see [here](http://yokolet.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/jruby-embed-red-bridge-update.html) for details.